# Insert a line break with inserted text in a Word document

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins

Building a word add-in using javascript (office.js) to insert text. So far unformatted text with .insertText. If I would like to insert the below, which function should be used?

- formatted text (for instance size, font, style)
- Line break
- Bullet point

Code:

```
results.items[i].insertText("Any text going here.", "replace");
```

How would I for instance insert a line break in the "Any text going here"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JavaScript, add a "line-break" (I'm assuming you mean the same as pressing ENTER in the UI - this is technically a *new paragraph*) using the string `"\n"`. So, for example:

```
results.items[i].insertText("Any text going here.\n", "replace");
```

Comment: Word knows both hard and soft returns. The `\n` is a hard return and will result in additional white space in certain Word styles (as if you press enter twice). You could also add a soft return in the string, this is the same as a `shift + enter` and will always result in a return on the next line without white space. You could add a soft return like this `String.fromCharCode(11)`.

Comment: @Fluous What you call a "hard return" is a paragraph break. The amount of "white space" that may or may not be added is a result of the paragraph formatting defined in the paragraph style associated with the paragraph: Space Before and/or Space After. What you call a "soft return" is simply a line break within the paragraph. It's always important to distinguish these and usually a line break is *not* the right thing - it's use should be strictly limited.

Comment: thank you for the clarification! A while back I was searching for this information (i.e. how to do a line break rather than a paragraph break). By posting this comment I hoped to help someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

- Use [`insertBreak`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.paragraph?view=office-js#insertbreak-breaktype--insertlocation-) for inserting breaks of different types. It could be line break, paragraph break, section break etc.

```
insertBreak(breakType: Word.BreakType, insertLocation: Word.InsertLocation): void;
```

- For adding lists like bullet points. Use [`startNewList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.paragraph?view=office-js#startnewlist--)

```
startNewList(): Word.List;
```

List example

```
//This example starts a new list stating with the second paragraph.
await Word.run(async (context) => {
    let paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
    paragraphs.load("$none"); //We need no properties.

    await context.sync();

    var list = paragraphs.items[1].startNewList(); //Indicates new list to be started in the second paragraph.
    list.load("$none"); //We need no properties.

    await context.sync();

    //To add new items to the list use start/end on the insert location parameter.
    list.insertParagraph('New list item on top of the list', 'Start');
    let paragraph = list.insertParagraph('New list item at the end of the list (4th level)', 'End');
    paragraph.listItem.level = 4; //Sets up list level for the lsit item.
    //To add paragraphs outside the list use before/after:
    list.insertParagraph('New paragraph goes after (not part of the list)', 'After');

    await context.sync();
});
```

- For formatting text, you can get hints by looking at [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.font?view=office-js#load-option-) here which set Font family and color of text.

```
//adding formatting like html style
var blankParagraph = context.document.body.paragraphs.getLast().insertParagraph("", "After");
blankParagraph.insertHtml('<p style="font-family: verdana;">Inserted HTML.</p><p>Another paragraph</p>', "End");
```

```
// another example using modern Change the font color
// Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
Word.run(function (context) {

    // Create a range proxy object for the current selection.
    var selection = context.document.getSelection();

    // Queue a commmand to change the font color of the current selection.
    selection.font.color = 'blue';

    // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
    // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
    return context.sync().then(function () {
        console.log('The font color of the selection has been changed.');
    });
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

The Word addin [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/word-tutorial) has a lot of nifty tricks for common tasks with code samples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
results.items[i].insertBreak(Word.BreakType.line,Word.InsertLocation.after);   
results.items[i].insertText("Any text going here.", Word.InsertLocation.replace);
```